Dual of closure
Currently I'm studying about abstract interpolation theory for my research. One of the basic ways to construct new interpolation spaces, given an interpolation space $E$ with respect to a compatible couple $(E_0,E_1)$ is to perform closures. More precisely, we consider (that's a notation I made by myself since the original seems poorly orientative) $\overline{E}^{\Delta}$ as the closure of $E_0\cap E_1$ with respect $E$ and $\overline{E}^\Sigma$ with respect to $E_0+E_1$. With these notations we can construct new intermediate spaces from the trivial intermediate spaces $E_i$, $i=0,1$. I thought that it would be interesting to look at dual spaces in this context, and a result that i think that could be true is the following $$(\overline{E}^\Delta)^*=\overline{(E^*)}^\Sigma,$$ and vice versa. I managed to prove it but i haven't advances. I didnt find anything related. What do you think? It could be true or there is just a trivial counterexample that i'm not visualizing. Thanks in advance

What do you mean by $\overline{(E^*)}^\Sigma$, take the closure in what space now? Also I suggest to check on $E = E_0 \cap E_1$ and $E=E_0+E_1$ and on the real interpolation spaces $(E_0,E_1)_{\theta,p}$ where we know (for $p < \infty$) that $E_0 \cap E_1$ is dense.

What does "I have n advances" mean? \ Your notation for closures is very tall, so you may want to consider whether you like the notation $\smash{\overline E}^\Delta$ \smash{\overline E}^\Delta.

"I haven't any advances" i wanted to write, sorry
